Is it safe to boot a firmware upgrade ISO image with Ventoy
Lenovo distributes its firmware and BIOS upgrade through Windows EXE files or bootable CD ISO files. Apparently the ISO files are not hybrid ones that can boot from USB flash drive, an actual CD is needed.
I use Linux, and I don't have a USB CD drive, but putting the image on a Ventoy USB flash drive allows to boot it, and the Ventoy documentation suggests it emulates an actual CD.
As this is about flashing firmware which could possibly brick my motherboard? I am wondering if it is safe to use Ventoy for that?

Yes, it's safe.
If it boots like it would if burned to a CD, there's no difference whatsoever in the end result for all intended purposes.
